# Embed a particular div of a website in another?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

I want to embed my one website inside another, both are mine. Both are wordpress website, there's this div class "data_table" , which i like to embed.,

Embed Code

```
<div id="PlaceToPutTable"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="//example.com/sample-post/" style="display:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Javascript

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var div = document.getElementById("PlaceToPutTable");
div.innerHTML = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("data_table").innerHTML;
```

I am seeing the whole website. am not seeing the individual content.

Comment: "both are mine" - Do they have the same domain? Otherwise this would be a violation of JavaScript's same origin security policy.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention.. both are different domains., totally different domains. I meant mine so as not to invite any downvote saying it's not ethical, but both are websites I own.

Comment: If they are different domains then this cannot work as it is a violation of JavaScript's same origin security policy. There are workarounds - do some research on JavaScript's same origin security policy with respect to iframes.